Galaxy A13 FRP Bypass
I have some A13's I am trying to get into. They are company phones and their previous users have left the business but with pin codes and accounts still on their company phones.
I am trying to get around FRP so I can reset these phones and put them to good use.
What I have tried so far

Using DroidKit, however it won't recognise the phone as USB debugging on turned off (and unable to turn it on as settings hidden behind passcode)
Flashing stock firmware on to the device (Still hit the same FRP problem)

Has any got any suggestions or advice?
Thanks

So you don't have an MDM solution and you didn't require your people with company owned phones to use a company managed email as the primary on your device? If not, then you are likely out of luck... FRP is getting better and better and is tougher and tougher all the time to circumvent. There are no viable solutions I am aware of to bypass this.
